# Firefox: Width of container for image isn't calculated correctly (Update 1)

Tags: css, image, firefox, flexbox, width

I created a chapterscoller tool for a video player.

The chapterscroller should let you scroll horizontally through a list of chapters. Each chapter is represented by a thumbnail image, a number and a time information. Since the images change depending on the content, their actual resolution and aspect ratio is not known as of now. To keep the aspect ratio I set `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;` on the image.
The container element for all chapters uses `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row;`. The currently selected chapter will be marked with class 'active-element' and therefore will be a little bit bigger than the other ones.

While the tool is already working as it should on other browsers, I noticed a weird behaviour in the latest Firefox (maybe it's also in earlier versions).

Only on Firefox (desktop and mobile) the width of the container used for the image, number and time is not set to the actual rendered width of the image, but to the intrinsic width of the image elements source image (in this case 2000px).
I also prepared an jsfiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/vsx_sieber/29wv4o0m/4/

This is the HTML code:

```
<div style="height: 25%;" class="chapterscroller">
  <div class="chapterscroller-container">
    <!-- Chapter 1 element -->
    <div class="chapterscroller-thumbnail" aria-disabled="false">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2Z3qPjo.png">
      <div class="slideNumber">1 / 10</div>
      <div class="time">0:00 - 9:59</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Chapter 2 element (also the active element) -->
    <div class="chapterscroller-thumbnail active-thumbnail" aria-disabled="false">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2Z3qPjo.png">
      <div class="slideNumber">2 / 10</div>
      <div class="time">10:00 - 19:59</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Any number of more chapter elements here -->
    <!-- Chapter X element -->
    <div class="chapterscroller-thumbnail" aria-disabled="false">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2Z3qPjo.png">
      <div class="slideNumber">X / 10</div>
      <div class="time">XX:XX - XX:XX</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.chapterscroller {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(34, 34, 40, 1));

  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-height: 20%;
}

.chapterscroller-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.chapterscroller-thumbnail {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;

  margin: auto 1px;

  cursor: pointer;

  height: 100%;
  height: calc(80% - 4px);

  width: auto;

  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0em 0em 0.3em #fff;
}

.chapterscroller-thumbnail:hover {
  height: calc(90% - 4px);
}

.chapterscroller-thumbnail.active-thumbnail {
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slideNumber {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Note that on latest Chrome, IE11 and Opera everything works just as expected. Only Firefox is having this problem.

**Is this a bug in Firefox or am I missing something here?**

**UPDATE:**

I was able to somewhat fix the problem by changing the positioning of the chapterscroller container from `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;` to `position: relative; width: 100%; height 100%`.

But Firefox is still applying some unused space on the right side of each chapter thumbnail. The Firefox dev tools tell me, that the container has the size of it's content. But the content is the image element and its size is smaller than the size of the container. How can this be?

I created a new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsx_sieber/29wv4o0m/17/